# Converting a Hebrew LyX file to PDF

Tags: lyx, pdf, unicode

I am trying to convert a mathematical hebrew file to PDF. I made this change below and the converting Ctrl+R succeeds, but if I write italics in the document the PDF does not read it as italics. What's wrong?[image]

Here is the input:
[image]

Here is the output:
[image]

Second question: A friend told me that Unicode may somehow help me to fix the bugs. Is it true and how? I have no experience with Unicode.

Comment: Does the font have an italic variant at all?

Comment: I don't know, but I like the David font and I have seen several David documents with italics.

Answer (score 1):

Install and then select a Hebrew font that has italics, such as David CLM from [Culmus.](http://culmus.sourceforge.net/download.html)  Decide whether you want them slanted right or left.

Comment: After I chose David CLM and wrote in italics the output was bold instead and I don't want that. What do you prefer to choose after pressing Documents -> Settings?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your question. David CLM does have italics, but you can choose any Hebrew font that works in your word processor.

Comment: The output was a combination of bold and italics, and I would like to omit the bold.

Comment: Also, if I want to change the slanting of all italics at once, how I do that?

Comment: @YoavAvidan I’m not completely sure I understand the problem, but if David CLM is heavier than you like, you might try `\setmainfont{David Libre}[AutoFakeSlant=-0.15]` from `fontspec`. (Or without the minus sign.)

Comment: @YoavAvidan You would need to [download the David Libre font](https://github.com/fonts/david-libre).